# Exclude any findings based off the keyword

Tags: powershell, ntfs

Found a useful line of code from https://blog.malwarebytes.com/101/2015/07/introduction-to-alternate-data-streams/

```
gci -Recurse | % { gi $_.FullName -Stream * } | where stream -ne ':$Data'
```

I've been out of touch with PowerShell for a while so trying to figure out how to include an `-Exclude` function to narrow down the output it feeds me. There is an element of the object called, "Stream" and when it finds the string, "Zone.Identifier", I want that object excluded (the whole thing, not just that one line). Here's an example below of output.

[image]

I tried the following but no luck.

```
gci -Recurse | % { gi $_.FullName -Stream * -Exclude "Zone.Identifier" } | where stream -ne ':$Data'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `-notin` operator with `where`:

```
gci -recurse | % { gi $_.FullName -stream *  } | where stream -notin ':$Data','Zone.Identifier'
```

You can also skip `%` (alias for `ForEach-Object`) completely and pipe the items directly to `Get-Item`:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse |Get-Item -Stream * |Where-Object Stream -notin ':$Data','Zone.Identifier'
```

(Expanded the alias names for better readability)